# Highcharts left alignment on x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to do a simple left alignment for the labels on the x-axis of a stacked bar chart using HighCharts API. No matter what label options I try nothing works.

I tried setting verticalAlignment: "bottom" and useHTML: "true" but depending upon the settings there's always something wrong. Is this a bug in HighCharts?

Here are some examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/ojbbry6c/ Properly left-aligned labels, but for some reason the chart overlaps the labels when set to left alignment?

```
labels: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                align: 'left',
                textAlign: 'left',
                useHTML: true,
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rx0zws1/1/ turn off left align and now the chart doesn't overlap, but the alignment is broken.

```
labels: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                //align: 'left',
                textAlign: 'left',
                useHTML: true,
            }
```

How do you make the labels on the x-axis left-align? For other chart types where the y-axis is on the left it works fine, but stackedbar alignment seems broken.

Comment: What do you mean the alignment is broken?

Comment: Click on the links to see examples? I thought I described it well. In the first example they're all aligned on the left, but they overlap the chart. On the second they don't overlap the chart and appear to the left properly, but they're not left justified, only the first label is. The other ones appear right justified.

Comment: The second label "Apples" should appear directly below the first label "Apples and Oranges" but it does not, its off to the right near the chart.

Comment: It looks to be connected with this Highcharts issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5286

Comment: @SpacePrez - you were - I kept looking at it from a vertical alignment point of view, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

The comment by @Grzegorz Blachlínski is correct, this was an issue here:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5286

But it's been resolved in highcharts v6+, and the solution is to use align in conjunction with "reserveSpace". This works:

```
align: "left",
reserveSpace: true,
```